# Insert value from JSON file into filename path

Tags: cp, json

I need to copy a file and rename it based on a value from a json file:

```
info.json
{
  "folderName": "berlin"
}
```

to get the `folderName` from json I can use:

`jq '.folderName' info.json`

to copy the file I can use:

`cp ~/foo.js /<folderName>/foo.js`

The goal is to create: `/berlin/foo.js`

But how can I dynamically rename the path using the value `berlin` from JSON file? Preferably in a single command?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use *command substitution*

```
cp ~/foo.js /$(jq '.folderName' info.json)/foo.js
```

Since JSON strings are quoted by default (unless `jq` is used with the `-r` raw output flag), there's no need to quote the `$(...)` in this case.